# How can i make a query of two different objects in the same column of one table, relationed to different columns in another table?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I have the tables

### people

id INTEGER

name

phone_number

PRIMARY KEY(id)

### phone_calls

id INTEGER

caller_number

receiver_number

year

month

day

duration

PRIMARY KEY(id)

I want to take the information like

| name1 (as caller) | name2 (as receiver) |
| --- | --- |
| nikolas | mary |
| kostas | bob |

i managed with
SELECT name, caller_number FROM people JOIN phone_calls ON people.phone_number = phone_calls.caller_number WHERE year =  AND month =  AND day =  AND duration = ;
to get

| name as caller | caller_number |
| --- | --- |
| nikolas | 6999999999 |
| kostas | 688888888 |

or with
SELECT name, receiver_number FROM people JOIN phone_calls ON people.phone_number = phone_calls.receiver_number WHERE year =  AND month = AND day =  AND duration = ;
to get

| name as receiver | receiver_number |
| --- | --- |
| mary | 6777777777 |
| bob | 6555555555 |

or with
SELECT caller,receiver_number FROM phone_calls WHERE year = AND month = AND day = AND duration ;
to get

| caller_number | receiver_number |
| --- | --- |
| 6999999999 | 6777777777 |
| 688888888 | 6555555555 |

or with
SELECT name, receiver_number FROM people JOIN phone_calls ON people.phone_number = phone_calls.caller_number WHERE year = AND month = AND day = AND duration =;
to get

| name as caller | receiver_number |
| --- | --- |
| nicolas | 6777777777 |
| kostas | 6555555555 |

so i get the name at the telephone number of the caller or the name and the telephone number of the receiver, but not name of the caller and name of the receiver in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 joins to get both caller and receiver's name. For example

```
SELECT caller.name, receiver.name
FROM phone_calls
JOIN people caller ON caller.phone_number = phone_calls.caller_number
JOIN people receiver ON receiver.phone_number = phone_calls.receiver_number
WHERE <your conditions>
```

Comment: thanks so much for the response! It worked!! I just dont understand the part JOIN people caller and JOIN people receiver. I mean that people is a table and caller is a column in another table. And when we are saying SELECT caller.name are we relation the two columns from both tables?

Comment: Caller and receiver in the join statement are just aliases. They are both represent for data from people table, so you can select caller.column_name to get info of caller (same for receiver). You can see mysql documentation for more understanding: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html